# How to Multiply Matrix Values By a Constant if a Condition is Met?

Tags: python, numpy

In python I have a matrix and I need to have that same matrix returned to me, except I have a rule, if there are elements in that matrix that are <0 I multiply their individual values by a constant. I am not sure how to go about doing this though.

Example: a=[[0, 2, 1, 4], [-2, 3, 5, 2]] and let's say my constant is -0.1, then I would be returned a=[[0, 2, 1, 4], [.2, 3, 5, 2]

Comment: What did you try? Can you give an example? Is it a list or a numpy array?

Comment: a is an array, and an example would be if a=[[0, 2, 1, 4], [-2, 3, 5, 2]] and let's say my constant is -0.1, then I would be returned a=[[0, 2, 1, 4], [.2, 3, 5, 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [55]: a = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(10,10))

In [56]: a
Out[56]:
array([[  7,   6,   0,   2,   3,  -9,   2,  -2,   9, -10],
       [  8,   4, -10,   5,   7,   6,   7,  -3,   1,  -3],
       [  5, -10,  -8,   4,  -2,  -9,   0,   8,  -1,   7],
       [  6,   7,   6,   2,  -3,   3,   0,  -7,  -6,  -4],
       [  8,   0,  -7,   7,   9,  -4,  -5,   7,  -5,  -9],
       [-10,  -9,  -6,  -9,  -1,   2,  -6,  -9,   8,  -3],
       [  5,  -3,  -6,  -5,   6,  -8, -10,   7,   3,  -5],
       [  9,   4,   5,   9,   2,  -5,  -8,   5,  -1,  -7],
       [ -9,  -7,  -7,  -3, -10,  -7,   3,  -1,   5,   3],
       [  0,  -4,   9,  -9,  -5,  -1,  -8,   9,  -4,  -5]])

In [57]: a[a<0] *= 10

In [58]: a
Out[58]:
array([[   7,    6,    0,    2,    3,  -90,    2,  -20,    9, -100],
       [   8,    4, -100,    5,    7,    6,    7,  -30,    1,  -30],
       [   5, -100,  -80,    4,  -20,  -90,    0,    8,  -10,    7],
       [   6,    7,    6,    2,  -30,    3,    0,  -70,  -60,  -40],
       [   8,    0,  -70,    7,    9,  -40,  -50,    7,  -50,  -90],
       [-100,  -90,  -60,  -90,  -10,    2,  -60,  -90,    8,  -30],
       [   5,  -30,  -60,  -50,    6,  -80, -100,    7,    3,  -50],
       [   9,    4,    5,    9,    2,  -50,  -80,    5,  -10,  -70],
       [ -90,  -70,  -70,  -30, -100,  -70,    3,  -10,    5,    3],
       [   0,  -40,    9,  -90,  -50,  -10,  -80,    9,  -40,  -50]])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I will accept when it allows me to.